# How can I add '#' symbol/emoji in a string such that it doesn't splits the string when `split('#')` method is called on it?

Tags: javascript, unicode, symbols, emoji, codepoint

Is there a way in JavaScript to display a symbol similar to '#' in a string such that `"Enter #time to check time".split('#')` doesn't break it into pieces?

It should return a complete string instead of `['Enter ','time to check time']`.

I tried using this '#️⃣' symbol in place of '#' but it still somehow gets detected. On further debugging I found out that this emoji is composed of 2 [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) out of which 1st one translates to unicode `\u0023` which is similar to that of the '#' symbol. And hence it splits the string.

This might seem like a stupid issue but the underlying use case is very interesting but unfortunately I could not share here due to confidential reasons. So, any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `includes('#')` test for a match with a regular expression like `/#[A-Za-z]+/` or something. If typical hashtags are not supposed to be detected as containing a `#` how exactly will the character be part of the string? Is there going to be whitespace after it?

Comment: Why exactly do you do `.split('#')` in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the answer but it doesn't fulfill the use case. I've updated the question to show the actual problem statement

Comment: @SebastianSimon updated the question. Please do have a look

Comment: @DeepakTerse I don’t see how your edit answers my question. _Why_ is the string split by `#`? Why is the string not left unmodified? What is the purpose of splitting? Can’t you find a different character to split on, or, better yet, a different string format, e.g. a more flexible one like JSON?

Comment: Try `＃` (U+FF03,  *Fullwidth Number Sign*) instead of `#️⃣` which  is composed of *3* code points `#` (U+0023,  *Number Sign*)
- `️` (U+FE0F,  *Variation Selector-16*)
- `⃣` (U+20E3,  *Combining Enclosing Keycap*).

Comment: So basically, this string is part of an action where we say something like `print#$current_time` or `print#$message`. and in this case the action is `print#Enter #time to check time`. So this splits the action into 3 parts. But actually there are 2 parts - action name and the parameter

Comment: @SebastianSimon And like you mentioned the underlying logic can be changed to support the '#' but I'm looking for any solution in the content itself

Comment: @DeepakTerse In that case, don't go looking for a different character to split by - instead just split it into only two parts! `const parts = string.split('#'); const action = parts.shift(); const parameter = parts.join('#');` being a common solution to that. Or use string methods for working with indices.

Comment: @JosefZ ur solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution here was to switch to full-width hash symbol which has a different unicode `U+FF03` whereas half-width hash symbol (which is the same as the hash symbol on the keyboard) has a unicode `U+0023`

Comment: This is not a solution, it's at best a workaround. Any of the two characters can still appear as a parameter.